# Highcharts - point markers fill color on gradient line

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have a highchart where I am using gradient colors for line, but I would like my point markers to take a color from that part of line and not to have gradient color on it's circle themselves, but not sure how to do that.

This is my code:

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
              marker: {
                fillColor: '#353A41',
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: null
              },
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: {
                      x1: 1,
                      y1: 0,
                      x2: 0,
                      y2: 0
                    },
                    stops: [
                      [0, Highcharts.Color('#962E74').setOpacity(0.1).get('rgba')],
                      [0.25, Highcharts.Color('#733F7D').setOpacity(0.1).get('rgba')],
                      [0.5, Highcharts.Color('#4E6585').setOpacity(0.1).get('rgba')],
                      [0.75, Highcharts.Color('#427188').setOpacity(0.1).get('rgba')],
                      [1, Highcharts.Color('#2A8B8E').setOpacity(0.1).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                color: {
                  linearGradient: {
                    x1: 1,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 0
                  },
                    stops: [
                      [0, Highcharts.Color('#962E74').setOpacity(1).get('rgba')],
                      [0.25, Highcharts.Color('#733F7D').setOpacity(1).get('rgba')],
                      [0.5, Highcharts.Color('#4E6585').setOpacity(1).get('rgba')],
                      [0.75, Highcharts.Color('#427188').setOpacity(1).get('rgba')],
                      [1, Highcharts.Color('#2A8B8E').setOpacity(1).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
            }
```

Comment: Markers are separate elements in SVG and are not able to extract part of gradient series. So you need to declare gradients per points individually.

Comment: Since, the amount of markers is gonna change dynamically, because users will have possibility of changing time intervals for the chart, do you know if it is possible to add colors based on percentage or the amount of markers like for linear gradient? For example, first 25% of the markers get one color next 25% get other color and so on.

Comment: Unfortnately this is not possible, so you need to create your own function which will do that. But you can try to use solid colosr and the zones. Docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.zones